# Angular Combine RxJs observable streams and get data when one of the streams produces an error

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 observable streams, each one is produced by a method that can either return an observable with data or an error like so:

```
getData(type: string, id: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get([apiUrl, 
                        this.getUrl(type, id)].join('/'));
}
```

And the streams are:

```
stream1$ = getData('data1, 'abcd');
stream2$ = getData('data2', 'zre4');
```

I need a way to combine those 2 streams into one, I have tried to use .zip and .combineLatest but when one request fails I get a 404 error, the onError callback gets called and I loose the data of the successful get request stream. What I need is a way to combine them and get the data even if one of the streams produces a 404 error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are few mothods like `.merge`, `.flatMap` available in the rxjs you can use the ..
for the merger you can merge both the result and get single set of stream data to use

```
Observable.merge(stream1$ = getData('data1, 'abcd'),
stream2$ = getData('data2', 'zre4')).subscribe( (result) => {
 consloe.log(result)
});
```

documetation for [rxjs merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html). You can use flatMap in case your requirement is in that way.

Answer (score 0):

For anynone interested I manage to resolve the issue by using the catch operator on both streams before merging them like so:

```
stream1$ = getData('data1, 'abcd').catch((error) => {
  return Observable.of(error);
});

stream2$ = getData('data2, 'zre4').catch((error) => {
  return Observable.of(error);
});
```

This way the merged observable gets the data of the "good" stream even if the other one fails. More details can be found here:

https://chrisnoring.gitbooks.io/rxjs-5-ultimate/content/error-handling.html

Thanks